# Try to Video Record using adb shell screenrecord Android 4.4

Tags: android, video-streaming, adb, android-4.4-kitkat, video-recording

I am try to create a video from terminal but I can't succeed. It gives error on terminal like this.

```
adb shell screenrecord  /sdcard/screenshotyyyy.mp4
ERROR: unable to create encoder input surface (err=-38)
WARNING: failed at 320x480, retrying at 720x1280
ERROR: unable to create encoder input surface (err=-38)
```

Comment: might fit for http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adb

Answer (score 15):

The screenrecord feature doesn't work in the AOSP emulator, because the software AVC encoder doesn't support the necessary features.  As noted in [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61682), the screenrecord binary will be removed from future emulator distributions to avoid confusion.

I don't expect support to be added in the near future, as this requires a bunch of work in the codec.