# Error while using adb shell screenrecord

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-4.4-kitkat, screen-recording

I have HTC HD2 flashed to Android 4.4 KitKat CM 11.0 ([The flash](http://nexushd2android.tytung.com/nexushd2-kitkat-cm11-0/v4-4)).
I try to capture video using **adb shell screenrecord** and got the same problem as: [Try to Video Record using adb shell screenrecord Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724058/try-to-video-record-using-adb-shell-screenrecord-android-4-4).
But I do not use an emulator, it's real phone.
What's problem? What do I do wrong?
Sorry for my KindaEnglish. Please, Use simple and easy English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please put here the exact command line. Also are you sure the path to your sdcard is correct ?